# java PHP regex expression

Tags: java, php, regex

i need help to validate expression for grid

two characters and 1 to 3 numbers

the minimum user can enter is AA1
the maximum user can enter is FZ280
everything between can be entered 
meens: first two character of string between AA and FZ

pos of string:
pos 1: uppercase character from A-F
pos 2: uppercase character from A-Z
pos 3: number if pos 4 and pos 5 not entered THEN from 1-9 ELSE from 1-2
pos 4: number if pos 5 not entered THEN from 0-9 ELSE from 1-8
pos 5: number from 1-9
white space and special characters are not allowed
examples:
Valid = AA1, AA29, BB89,  etc... AB101, FZ207, 
inValid = AA0, AA01, AA001, GAxxx, a1, A1,

I need this for JAVA and after for PHP

I spend now to much time on this, i hope somebody can help me

Thanks

Comment: `I need this for JAVA and after for PHP`. So how much will you pay for me..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that's quite well-specified, so here goes:

```
^[A-F][A-Z](?:280|2[0-7][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
[A-F]        # Match a letter A-F
[A-Z]        # Match a letter A-Z
(?:          # Start of group that matches...
 280         # either 280
|            # or
 2[0-7][0-9] # a number between 200 and 279
|            # or
 1[0-9][0-9] # a number between 100 and 199
|            # or
 [1-9][0-9]? # a number between 1 and 99
)            # End of group
$            # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/fL8kE8/1).

Comment: can it also be validated on FN for the last vertical. ex begin AA1 last FN280

Comment: Yes, then the first part needs to be `^(?:F[A-N]|[A-E][A-Z])(?:...`.

Comment: +1, didn't see that as off-topic either.